# Did Tony Stark ever know that Captain Rogers saved him during Captain America: The Winter Soldier (2014)?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, iron-man, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

At the moment that the three Heli-carriers are in the air during the events of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier (2014)*, targets are acquired all over the place, including the Stark/Avengers Tower in which Tony Stark was located:

[image]

**Did Tony ever know later on that Steve practically saved his life?**

Comment: Well, Stark didn't know that his father was killed by Hydra either, so I'd assume he simply didn't bother to find out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming Tony Stark is one of the most intelligent people on the planet in MCU, he could easily learn the details of what happened in *The Winter Soldier* without asking anybody.

We already know he can hack S.H.I.E.L.D.'s systems (and other government systems) from various Marvel movies.

[image]

([Also see the hack scene in Iron Man 2.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_D-rUxXIAw))

Steve wouldn't tell Tony that he saved his life. It's not one his character traits.

The events of of *The Winter Soldier* were huge in the MCU. When news of HYDRA’s involvement broke out, Tony Stark must have done research about what happened to learn the dirty secrets of <del>S.H.I.E.L.D.</del> HYDRA, and have come across some information about him being a potential target on HYDRA's radar.

the MCU is a non-comic-book-based universe. You can predict the events of the movies before they open but the context can be changed by the producers to create plot twists. Therefore I don't think I will try to provide a comic book reference.

Comment: That short gif is giving me a headache...

Comment: Not sure why that's a gif at all. The subtitle is the only part we really need.

Comment: @DCShannon I like gifs.